# Module does not recognize itself to be part of package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, python-packaging

I've created a Python3 project with [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage/) with the following structure (simplified for readability):

```
── docs
│   ├── ...
....
├── my_application
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_application.py
│   └── util
|       └── utility.py
├── README.rst
├── requirements_dev.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   ├── test_my_application.py
│   └── test_utility.py
└── ...
```

**my_application.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from my_application.util import utility

utility.hello_utility()

def hello_app():
    return "Main App"
```

**test_my_application.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pytest

from my_application import my_application

def test_main_app():
    assert my_application.hello_app() == 'Main App'
```

With these `import` statements, my tests run fine but running the application gives the following error:

```
from my_application.util import utility
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_application.util';
'my_application' is not a package
```

Changing that import in `my_application.py` to `from util import utility` reverses the situation: The program runs but the tests can't import the main module with `from my_application import my_application` anymore.

Weirdly enough, the following still works:

**test_utility.py**

```
from my_application.util import utility
def test_utility():
    assert utility.hello_utility() == 'Found'
```

I know, I can probably solve this by applying one of the usual hacks, e.g., appending to the `sys.path` or modifying the `PYTHONPATH` variable, but I hope to understand why the main module is not recognizing itself being part of the package when other modules do. I'm aware of the fact that it also depends on how and from where you run your modules. In my case, I only want to run the main module `my_application.py` directly and obviously the tests.

Comment: Always always *always* use `python -m`, or else a `setup.py`-created script. Running `python path/foo.py` is fundamentally broken.

Comment: `python -m my_application.py` doesn't work in any of the described scenarios, unfortunately.

Comment: `.py` isn't part of the module name.

Comment: No, o11c is telling you to run the *module*, not a .py file. Run `python  -m my_application` (and preferably use a `__main__.py` file in that package), or `python -m my_application.my_application`.

Comment: Credit to @o11c and thanks to @martijn-pieters for clarifying. This actually works when referencing the top-level package in all import statements, like so: `from my_application.util import utility`. So I guess I have to assume that Python's import system is pretty messed up, at least in this respect.

Answer (score -1):

You need an `__init__.py` in the util folder for utility to be imported properly.  The folder is not seen to be part of the package because the file is missing.  The error message is telling you that there is no package, this should fix that for you.

Comment: `__init__.py` hasn't been necessary since an early python3 version (3.3?)

Comment: I should have mentioned, I tried adding __init__.py to util and it didn't work. But, also, the problems seems to be related to the top level package, not the util package.

Comment: High quality downvotes when all I see is python3.x tag and nothing more specific for version info.